# CUDA: Is it reasonable to load an object into shared memory like shown?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'll have an object which is accessed by all threads of a block, therefore I plan to store it in shared memory. I created the attached class to load the object from global memory into shared memory.

The idea is simple: Each thread loads one word of the object. The shared memory can not be a member, therefore it is defined externally.

The class seems to work so far. **But is it a reasonable approach or will I likely run into problems?** I'm not asking for a general discussion of coding style, but for dangerous non-obvious pitfalls or significant drawbacks.

```
template <class T>
class SharedMemoryObjectLoader{

    public:

        // each thread will load one word
        using WORDTYPE = int;

        // compute the number of words (rounding up)
        static constexpr int N_WORDS = (sizeof(T) + sizeof(WORDTYPE) - 1) / sizeof(WORDTYPE);

        // load the object behind 'globalPtr' into shared memory location 'smemPtr'
        __device__ static T* load(WORDTYPE* smemPtr, T* globalPtr){

            WORDTYPE* smemWordPtr = reinterpret_cast<WORDTYPE*>(smemPtr);
            WORDTYPE* globalWordPtr = reinterpret_cast<WORDTYPE*>(globalPtr);


            if(N_WORDS > blockDim.x){
                // we assume that an object has less words than the number of threads
                assert(0);
            }
            else{
                if(N_WORDS > threadIdx.x){
                    // each thread with an id smaller than the number of words will load one word
                    smemWordPtr[threadIdx.x] = globalWordPtr[threadIdx.x];
                }
            }

            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(smemPtr);

        }

};
```

Load an object:

```
using Loader = CommandDataPerBlockLoader<Obj>
__shared__ typename Loader::WORDTYPE shMem[Loader::N_WORDS];
Obj* shObj = CommandDataPerBlockLoader::load(shMem, objPtrInGlobalMem);
```

Comment: If your thread block is not 1 dimensional (ie. `blockDim.y` or `blockDim.z` are greater than 1) you're going to be doing some work you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question: for what you are doing to be well-defined (from the point of view of C++), your type has to meet the requirements of [`TriviallyCopyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable):

> The only trivially copyable types are scalar types, trivially copyable classes, and arrays of such types/classes (possibly const-qualified, but not volatile-qualified).
>
> A trivially copyable class is a class that
>
> 1. Has no non-trivial copy constructors (this also requires no virtual functions or virtual bases)
> 2. Has no non-trivial move constructors
> 3. Has no non-trivial copy assignment operators
> 4. Has no non-trivial move assignment operators
> 5. Has a trivial destructor

In host code, you may test whether `T` qualifies as such with the trait [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable).

Note that your code currently does not contain a memory barrier and is therefore subject to race conditions.

You also have to make sure that the object you are loading is aligned on `WORDTYPE`.

Comment: "No performance difference"? I'm not sure this is true. The object in this case could easily be thousands of bytes, and I'd expect much better performance distributing this load over many threads compared to one.

Comment: This is simply not correct.  The correct way to load data from global to shared memory is in a thread-cooperative fashion.  The OP's code demonstrates this, and it is most definitely higher performance than having a single thread do it.  To have a single thread load 2 items requires two memory transactions.  To have 2 threads load 2 (adjacent) items requires only one transaction.

Comment: I agree with Robert. The extreme case is where you have a warp-wide 32 word load vs one thread loading each word. The former is one instruction/transaciton. The latter is 32 instructions/transactions, and will be slower.I also don't see how broadcasts to anything larger than a warp would work. You might see some hits in L2, but given it is legal, in the absense of `__syncthreads()`, for one warp to reach the end of a kernel before another has started, I don't see how this would work.

Comment: I agree with Robert and Jez on the loading performance. Clearly, one could also just read the object members from global memory and hope that caching will improve performance (read the first member and immediately have the first 128 bytes also on-chip). But in that case, the risk is that the object would be thrown out of cache (even though I need it in future) to keep other data in cache which WON'T be reused.

Comment: The [maximum load by a single thread from global memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) is 16 bytes per transaction.  Therefore, if all the loading is done by a single thread, it will require at least `sizeof(Obj)/16` transactions.  Yes, after the first transaction, some of the following transactions will hit in the cache, but that still represents inefficiency and performance loss (as measured in the number of instructions required to move the object to shared memory).

Comment: OTOH, I can use all the threads in a warp together, and by having them load adjacent "elements" (chunks, whatever) of the object, they can complete the same operation in at least `sizeof(Obj)/(16*8)` transactions.  This requires fewer transactions, fewer instructions dispatched to the warp,  and is generally a more efficient use of the memory subsystem, cache effects notwithstanding.  The concepts apply equally to the global memory load and the shared memory store, in terms of number of instructions, number of transactions, and efficiency.

Comment: [This](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0514-GTC2012-GPU-Performance-Analysis.pdf) may help.